# SVN command-line: Find current HEAD revision of a branch

Tags: bash, svn, command-line, branch

As part of a script I'm writing, I'm trying to grab the latest revision number within a *given branch* in SVN.

I had tried the following code (where ${sourcebranch} is the SVN URL for my branch):

```
svn info ${sourcebranch} | awk '/Revision/ { print $2; }'
```

However, this seems to give me the latest revision number for the *entire repository*, not just the branch.

I really just want the branch... any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Use `log` instead:

```
svn log --limit 1 ${sourcebranch}
```

This will return the last commit to the branch, similar to this output:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r14159 | author_name | 2014-04-25 18:54:49 -0400 (Fri, 25 Apr 2014) | 5 lines

log message

------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

From there, just parse the `r####` field.

Answer (score 2):

"Revision" value is applied to whole repo, you need "Last changed rev".